# How to get Google Analytics dimension/metric description in multi-language?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using this API to get a list of dimensions/metrics from Google Analytics: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/analytics/v3/analytics.metadata.columns.list?reportTy..., however, I just realized the API only supports 'uiName', 'description' in English! is that true? is there any work around to support multi-language? Thanks!

```
"items": [
{
"id": "ga:userType",
"kind": "analytics#column",
"attributes": {
"type": "DIMENSION",
"dataType": "STRING",
"group": "User",
"status": "PUBLIC",
"uiName": "User Type",
"description": "A boolean, either New Visitor or Returning Visitor, indicating if the users are new or returning.",
"allowedInSegments": "true",
"addedInApiVersion": "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is true the Meta data api only returns data in english.  You are going to have to translate the metadata names to your chosen language yourself after you have downloaded the data you need